# write.AnnotatedDataFrame not found in R

Tags: r, dataframe

The following code gives an error message:

```
library(Biobase)
a <- AnnotatedDataFrame()
write.AnnotatedDataFrame(a, "a.txt")
```

> Error: could not find function "write.AnnotatedDataFrame"

This is strange, as the [following page](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/Biobase/html/read.AnnotatedDataFrame.html) gives documentation for this function.

I was unable to find more information about `write.AnnotatedDataFrame` through searching. Is this function deprecated, in a package, or something else? I am running R version 3.1.3.

Comment: Which version of `Biobase` do you use? `write.AnnotatedDataFrame` function exists in version `2.27`, not in version `2.21`. See here: http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/news/Biobase/NEWS. I would recommend to upgrade R and update your packages.

Comment: I am using version 2.26. Is it installed in that version?

Comment: Oh apparently not, so it was added in version 2.27.....